# Listview Text Property in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, text

I'm new to WPF and I noticed we can't use `listview` text property

```
listview1.SelectedItems[0].Text = textBlock.text;
```

But I want to change name of a selected item in my `listview` so I also tried

```
listView.SelectedItems[0] = textBlock.Text;
```

But that didn't work either last code also gives me an error in this line as well

```
textBlock.Text = myList[listView.Items.IndexOf(listView.SelectedItems[0])].ItemName;
```

also I have a get,set method for `myList`

```
public string ItemName { get; set; }
```

also the `xaml` code for listview

```
        <ListView x:Name="listView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="301" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="142" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" BorderThickness="1" Foreground="Black" SelectionChanged="listView_SelectionChanged">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: can you provide more information ?, XAML code, code behind?

Comment: sure, I added XAML code for listview as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SelectedItems` is a read-only property that's used to get the selected items of your `ListView` when the selection mode is set to `Multiple`, if you want to change some properties value in the selected ListView's Item you must do that on the `SelectedItem` instead, and it will be much more comfortable to you if you implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface (to notify the UI when a property in the ListView's `SelectedItem` has changed), so:

- define your `listView` in xaml, bind its `ItemSource` and `SelectedItem`

  ```
  <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ListViewCollection}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedListViewItem,Mode=TwoWay}" SelectionMode="Single"></ListView>
  ```
- then in the codebehind (or ViewModel), define your collection and your selected item, implement the `INotifypropertyChanged` and set the `DataContext`

  ```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window,INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
      private ObservableCollection<ListViewItemObj> _listViewCollection;
      private ListViewItemObj _selectedListViewItem;


      public ObservableCollection<ListViewItemObj> ListViewCollection
      {
          get { return _listViewCollection; }
          set
          {
              if (Equals(value, _listViewCollection)) return;
              _listViewCollection = value;
              OnPropertyChanged();
          }
      }

      public ListViewItemObj SelectedListViewItem
      {
          get { return _selectedListViewItem; }
          set
          {
              if (Equals(value, _selectedListViewItem)) return;
              _selectedListViewItem = value;
              OnPropertyChanged();
          }
      }


      public MainWindow()
      {
          InitializeComponent();
          this.DataContext = this;
      }
   }
  ```
- To update the `ListView`'s `SelectedItem` simply do that to the `SelectedListViewItem` property.

**Update**

let's say your `ListView` shows a collection of the following class:

```
public class ListViewItemObj:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;
    private string _val;

    public String Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _name) return;
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public String Val
    {
        get { return _val; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _val) return;
            _val = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

And your code behind looks like below :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window,INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private ObservableCollection<ListViewItemObj> _listViewCollection = new ObservableCollection<ListViewItemObj>()
    {
       new ListViewItemObj(){Name = "item 1",Val = "Val1"},
       new ListViewItemObj(){Name = "item 2",Val = "Val2"},
       new ListViewItemObj(){Name = "item 3",Val = "Val3"},

    };
    private ListViewItemObj _selectedListViewItem;


    public ObservableCollection<ListViewItemObj> ListViewCollection
    {
        get { return _listViewCollection; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _listViewCollection)) return;
            _listViewCollection = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ListViewItemObj SelectedListViewItem
    {
        get { return _selectedListViewItem; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _selectedListViewItem)) return;
            _selectedListViewItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;

    }
 }
```

Here is a simple example of how to show and update the selected `ListViewItem` :

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListView Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding ListViewCollection}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedListViewItem,Mode=TwoWay}" SelectionMode="Single">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Val}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Text="Selected Item"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding SelectedListViewItem.Val,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Can you give me an example for update? If you are free :)